# How to use JMF on an Applet embedded in a HTML page

Tags: java, applet, jmf

I have a Java applet (developed in NetBeans 7.4 and using JMF) for taking pictures from a web camera, it initializes the webcam automatically at startup (by using JMF)...

**(APPLET)**

[image]

For making it run it's necessary to add the jmf.properties file inside same directory of JAR file like this:

[image]

I tried to show this component inside a HTML page for taking snapshots from a WebBrowser but the JMF doesn't work there, everytime I run it I get this message (trying to initialize the webCam with JMF):

[image]

then it just displays the applet

[image]

this is my HTML code (Generated by Netbeans)

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
   <TITLE>Applet HTML Page</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>

<!--
*** GENERATED applet HTML launcher - DO NOT EDIT IN 'BUILD' FOLDER ***

If you need to modify this HTML launcher file (e.g., to add applet parameters), 
copy it to where your applet class is found in the SRC folder. If you do this, 
the IDE will use it when you run or debug the applet.

Tip: To exclude an HTML launcher from the JAR file, use exclusion filters in 
the Packaging page in the Project Properties dialog.

For more information see the online help.
-->

<H3><HR WIDTH="100%">Applet HTML Page<HR WIDTH="100%"></H3>

<P>
<APPLET codebase="classes" code="com/xxx/pantallas/CamaraApplet.class" width=350 height=200></APPLET>
</P>

<HR WIDTH="100%"><FONT SIZE=-1><I>Generated by NetBeans IDE</I></FONT>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

and the directory from where I open my HTML

[image]

Any help for making the webCam running from the HTML as well I'll appreciate

---

Requirements:

- Have installed JDK 32Bit version
- Have installed JMF: [Link to download page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-java-client-419417.html#7372-jmf-2.1.1e-oth-JPR)
- **Full project:**       [Link to download page](http://www.mediafire.com/?5w18c1hkdy9mw92)
- **Libraries required***** : [Link to download page](http://www.mediafire.com/download/ns6yuz2192apnf6/JMF_project_libraries.rar)

***libraries are required for using JMF on the project

For make this project running I use:

- 2 classes
- 1 applet (main)
- 1 HTML file

---

**CameraApplet.java (Applet)**

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import javax.media.Player;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import static com.sun.java.accessibility.util.AWTEventMonitor.addWindowListener;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class CameraApplet extends javax.swing.JApplet {
    private Player  p1;

    public  Player  getPlayer()             {return p1;}
    public  void    setPlayer(Player pin)   {p1 = pin;}
    public  JPanel  getCamera()             {return panelCam;}

    private void    initComponents2() {

        //Register all the listeners of the Events
        AuxClass e = new AuxClass(this);
        addWindowListener(e);
        jmCArchivo.addActionListener(e);

        //Loads in menu all detected devices
        AuxClass.DevicesMenuApplet(this, jmDispositivos);

        //applet size
        setSize(680, 840);

        //Autostarts camera
        AuxClass.setCameraApplet(CameraApplet.this,
                                 AuxClass.detectAvailableWebCameras().get(0),
                                 0);
    }

    @Override
    public void init() {
        //Establecer los valores de look and feel del applet
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } 
        catch(ClassNotFoundException | IllegalAccessException | InstantiationException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e){
            AuxClass.showErrorMessage(null, "Ocurrio un error: " + e.toString());
        }

        /* crea y muestra el applet */
        try {
            java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    initComponents();
                    initComponents2();
                }
            });
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException | InvocationTargetException e){
            AuxClass.showErrorMessage(null, "Ocurrio un error: " + e.toString());
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the init() method to initialize the
     * form. WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
     * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        panelCam = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
        jmCapturar = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        jmCArchivo = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        jmDispositivos = new javax.swing.JMenu();

        setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(640, 480));

        panelCam.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Camara Web"));
        panelCam.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(640, 480));
        panelCam.setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());

        jmCapturar.setText("Capturar");

        jmCArchivo.setText("En Archivo");
        jmCapturar.add(jmCArchivo);

        jMenuBar1.add(jmCapturar);

        jmDispositivos.setText("Dispositivos");
        jMenuBar1.add(jmDispositivos);

        setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(panelCam, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 442, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(panelCam, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 358, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
    }// </editor-fold>                        


    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem jmCArchivo;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jmCapturar;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jmDispositivos;
    private javax.swing.JPanel panelCam;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

---

**AuxClass.java**

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowListener;
import java.awt.image.RenderedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.media.Buffer;
import javax.media.CannotRealizeException;
import javax.media.CaptureDeviceInfo;
import javax.media.Format;
import javax.media.Manager;
import javax.media.MediaLocator;
import javax.media.NoPlayerException;
import javax.media.Player;
import javax.media.cdm.CaptureDeviceManager;
import javax.media.control.FormatControl;
import javax.media.control.FrameGrabbingControl;
import javax.media.format.RGBFormat;
import javax.media.format.VideoFormat;
import javax.media.format.YUVFormat;
import javax.media.util.BufferToImage;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class AuxClass implements WindowListener,ActionListener{

    private final CameraApplet padreApplet;

    public AuxClass(CameraApplet padreApplet){this.padreApplet = padreApplet;}

    //Menu Actions
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getActionCommand().equals("En Archivo")){
                AuxClass.saveImageFile(AuxClass.capturePhoto(padreApplet.getPlayer()),
                                                              AuxClass.SaveFileAsDialog(padreApplet));  
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {AuxClass.stopPlayer(padreApplet.getPlayer());}
    @Override
    public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
    }
    @Override
    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
    }
    @Override
    public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {
    }
    @Override
    public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {
    }
    @Override
    public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {
    }
    @Override
    public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {
    }





    //This method handles the Saving image file as. Jpg
    public static File SaveFileAsDialog(Component padre){

        JFileChooser    f;
        File            imageFile   = null;
        String          imagePath   = "";
        f                           = new JFileChooser();

        f.setDialogTitle("Save File As...");
        f.showSaveDialog(padre);

        if(f.getSelectedFile() != null){
            imagePath  = f.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();

            if (imagePath.lastIndexOf(".") > 0)
                imagePath  = imagePath.substring(0,imagePath.lastIndexOf("."));

            imagePath   = imagePath + ".jpg";
            imageFile   = new File(imagePath);
        }
        return imageFile;
    }

    public static void showErrorMessage(Component padre,String mensaje){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(padre,mensaje,"Captura Camara Web ",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }


    //This is the link between camera and the player class first time you turn the camera on
    public static void setCameraApplet(CameraApplet camera,String device,int format){
        Player player   = AuxClass.createPlayer(device, format);
        camera.setPlayer(player);
        AuxClass.startPlayer(player);
        camera.getCamera().add(player.getVisualComponent());
    }



    //----------------------------------------Player methods----------------------------------------
        public static void startPlayer(Player p){
        if(p!=null) p.start();
    }

    public static void stopPlayer(Player p){
        if(p!=null){
            p.stop();
            p.deallocate();
            p.close();
        }
    }

    public static Image capturePhoto(Player p){
        Image img   = null;
        if(p != null){
            FrameGrabbingControl fgc    = (FrameGrabbingControl)p.getControl("javax.media.control.FrameGrabbingControl");
            Buffer               buf    = fgc.grabFrame();
            BufferToImage        btoi   = new BufferToImage((VideoFormat)buf.getFormat());
            img                         = btoi.createImage(buf);
        }
        else{
            AuxClass.showErrorMessage(null, "¡Player has not started yet!");
        }
        return img;
    }

    public static void saveImageFile(Image img,File imagenArch){       
        String format = "JPG";
        try {
            if(img !=null && imagenArch!=null)
                ImageIO.write((RenderedImage) img, format , imagenArch);
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            AuxClass.showErrorMessage(null, "Disk write error: " + e.toString());
        }
    }    

    //JDevices methods
        //returns webCam's name selected
    public static CaptureDeviceInfo returnDevice(String name){
        return CaptureDeviceManager.getDevice(name);
    }

    //open webCamera selected
    public static MediaLocator openDevice(CaptureDeviceInfo cdi){
        return cdi.getLocator();
    }

    //Crea un Player a partir del nombre del dispositivo y del indice del formáto que se desea aplicar
    public static Player createPlayer(String device,int f){        
        Player p = null;

        try {
            p                           = Manager.createRealizedPlayer(openDevice(returnDevice(device)));
            Format []formats;
            formats                     = getFormats(device);
            FormatControl formatControl = (FormatControl)p.getControl("javax.media.control.FormatControl");
            formatControl.setFormat (formats[f]);
        } 
        catch (CannotRealizeException | IOException | NoPlayerException e) {
            AuxClass.showErrorMessage(null, "Input-Output Error: \n" + e.toString());
        }
        return p;
    }

    //Returns available formats, passing device's name
    public static Format[] getFormats(String name){
        CaptureDeviceInfo   cdi1        = returnDevice(name);
        Format              []formats   = cdi1.getFormats();
        return formats;
    }

    //Switches player's resolutions
    public static void changeResolution(Player p,String device,int format){
        if(p != null) p.stop();

        Format []formats            = getFormats(device);
        FormatControl formatControl = (FormatControl)p.getControl("javax.media.control.FormatControl");
        formatControl.setFormat (formats[format]);
        p.start();
    }

    //Loads all the cameras detected and its actions within a JMenu object 
    public static void DevicesMenuApplet(CameraApplet camera, JMenu devices){

        List<String> cameraList = detectAvailableWebCameras();
        Format[] formatsArray;

        for(int j= 0; j< cameraList.size(); j++){
            JMenu               menuFormato     = new JMenu(cameraList.get(j));
            JMenuFormato        cameraRes       = null;
            CaptureDeviceInfo dev               = CaptureDeviceManager.getDevice(cameraList.get(j));
            formatsArray                        = dev.getFormats();

              //get the formats/resolutions availables:
              for(int i = 0; i < formatsArray.length; i++){

                  if(formatsArray[i].getEncoding().compareTo("yuv") == 0){
                      //this returns a menu element with label of the resolution and its actionlistener
                      cameraRes = new JMenuFormato(cameraList.get(j), 
                                                  formatsArray[i].getEncoding()+" "+
                                                 ((YUVFormat)formatsArray[i]).getSize().width + "x" +
                                                 ((YUVFormat)formatsArray[i]).getSize().height, 
                                                  i,
                                                 ((YUVFormat)formatsArray[i]).getSize().width ,
                                                 ((YUVFormat)formatsArray[i]).getSize().height ,
                                                  camera,
                                                  camera.getCamera());
                  }
                  else 
                  if(formatsArray[i].getEncoding().compareTo("rgb") == 0){
                      cameraRes = new JMenuFormato(cameraList.get(j),
                                                  formatsArray[i].getEncoding()+" "+
                                                  ((RGBFormat)formatsArray[i]).getSize().width+"x"+
                                                  ((RGBFormat)formatsArray[i]).getSize().height,
                                                  i,
                                                  ((RGBFormat)formatsArray[i]).getSize().width,
                                                  ((RGBFormat)formatsArray[i]).getSize().height,
                                                   camera,
                                                   camera.getCamera());
                  }
                  menuFormato.add(cameraRes);//Adds the menu to JMenu list
              }
              devices.add(menuFormato);     
            }     
    }

    //Detects all the camera devices detected inside a List
    public static List<String> detectAvailableWebCameras(){
        //make a reference to a JMF function for obtaining the devices
        List<String> deviceList = CaptureDeviceManager.getDeviceList(null); 
        List<String> cameraList = new ArrayList<>();
        Iterator it             = deviceList.iterator();         
        String name             = "";                            //Stores all the names of the devices
        while (it.hasNext()){                                    //Makes a cycle for listing all stored devices
          CaptureDeviceInfo cdi = (CaptureDeviceInfo)it.next();  //Get device info
          name                  =  cdi.getName();                //Get detected device's name

          //Filter only camera devices
          if(name.indexOf("Image") != -1){cameraList.add(name);}
      }
    return cameraList;
    }

}
```

---

**JMenuFormato.java**

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

//this class implements logic for obtaining menus and resolutions JFrame
public class JMenuFormato extends JMenuItem implements ActionListener{

    private final int           width;
    private final int           high;
    private final int           ordinal;

    private final JPanel        modifiable;
    private final String        device;

    private final CameraApplet  cameraApplet;

    //Constructores (Version Applet y version JFrame)
     public JMenuFormato(String device,String label,int ordinal,int width,int high,CameraApplet cameraApplet,JPanel modifiable){

        super(label);

        this.modifiable     = modifiable;
        this.width          = width;
        this.high           = high;
        this.cameraApplet   = cameraApplet;
        this.device         = device;
        this.ordinal        = ordinal;
        this.addActionListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //Acciones para Applet (Class)
            if(cameraApplet.getPlayer() == null){
                AuxClass.setCameraApplet(cameraApplet, device, ordinal);
            }
            else{
                AuxClass.changeResolution(cameraApplet.getPlayer(),device, ordinal);
            }   
        cameraApplet.setSize(width+200, high+200); 
    }
}
```

---

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>WebCam app</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div><applet code="CameraApplet.class" archive="CapturaCamaraWeb.jar" width="680" height="840"></applet></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Ensure the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) is configured to show for applets & JWS apps.  If there is no output at the default level, raise it and try again. 3) *"this is my HTML code (Generated by Netbeans)"*  Uggh.. I see Netbeans has done its usual 'hatchet hob' on that HTML.  It is wrong, but probably not the major problem. 4) *"..is necessary to add the jmf.properties file inside same directory of JAR.."*  No it isn't.  There are a number of ways to provide that resource to clients..

Comment: SSCCE never done that before, as I understood it's like a light version of my code, let me see gonna build something and post the code of my classes

Comment: Be sure to **read** the article before making an edit to the question.  An SSCCE has very specific requirements.

Comment: done, I have my code simplified and translated all english, I'm using five classes, an applet and a HTML, I hope to make it as simple as is required, if not, I'll update this to a server because I really need the help dude

Comment: An SSCCE is **one** source file.  To achieve that, demote the classes without `main(String[])` to default access and copy/paste them in at the end of the source that has a `main(..)`.  Do that and I'll look more into it.

Comment: okay I reduced it just to 2 java clasess, an applet (main) and the HTML for the main issue, I could not make one java class because one both has different constructors and one extends JMenuItem, I don't have enough skills yet pal, gonna upload the change

Comment: *"one extends JMenuItem"*  Well that is a 'screaming red flag'.  It is rarely necessary to extend GUI components.  In 14 years of Java development I've needed to do that for a menu item exactly (counts) **0 times.**

Comment: I'll polish my program skills I'm kinda new developing in Java friend if you please could help me out with this issue I'll appreciate for real

Comment: *"I'll polish my program skills.."*  Let's get a few things sorted.  1) The advice so far offered is directed towards **getting it working** but at this stage, the source of the error is unclear. 2) You use the term 'friend'.  I'm am not your friend.  (I'm not your enemy either.. but let's not get confused about what this exchange is about.  It is technical, not social.)  You want friends?  Go to FaceBook.  You want technical advice?  Come to SO and supply as much information as necessary to get it sorted.

Comment: After I post this comment I'll put some time into looking into the current code to see if I can get it working here (on this PC).

Comment: I appreciate it, I wont call you friend again thanks for your support

Comment: I've managed to get the applet on-screen as an application  (it is easier, since the code does not need to be digitally signed).  I'm not sure if it can be classed as 'progress' though.  Once on-screen, if I select "Capturar" I see a save file chooser.  After typing a file name and clicking OK the message "jPlayer has not started yet!".  BTW - this applet is needlessly overly complicated to get to just this stage.  I should not have to 'select menu items' or 'click things' before it fails.  Also, you do realize this code will need to be digitally signed, right?  ..

Comment: .. 1) Deploy GUI to client.  Not an easy task, and not something that a newbie should attempt,  but not rocket science. 2)  `Applet` crank up the difficulty to 'hard' due to 'browser/JRE interaction problems. 3)  JMF integrating an abandoned & unsupported API that is used be very few other developers. 'Really hard' (due to lack of experienced help, and partial lack of interest)  4) A digitally signed, fully trusted applet that uses JMF.  **Holy Crap!**  Come back to this problem in a *..couple of years.*

Comment: 1) Yup I know about digital sign but I didn't added it since is not part of the issue pending to solve.

2) To tell the truth I found the java project on a Java Development site, studied the code and fixed some of the things I understood with my current skills. 

3) Some things can't wait a couple of years because of my job and I'm willing to learn, do you know another way or API to make the webcam work on a web browser with better image quality?

4)thanks for the support